# Could someone give me a good explanation for Variable scope and callbacks?

Tags: c#, lambda, scope

I feel like I should know exactly how this works since I use it regularly and it seems to work, but I don't. As an example, how would this behave:

```
void MyMethod()
{    
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        DoSomeWork(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        });
    }
}
```

How does the scope of `i` change? Is the value copies over to the callback or does the callback function have access to the variable when it is called? Will the variable thus be in memory after `MyMethod` has long been finished?

Is there a good explanation for these kinds of things, especially when using lambda and `async` methods?

Comment: Man this site has changed

Comment: This is called a `closure`. http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter5/closures.aspx

Comment: I think this is a perfectly reasonable question - but I suspect it's a duplicate. Trying to find one now.

Comment: @roryap: The question asks for an explanation - while that *could* be an off-site resource, I think it's reasonable for it to be in an answer, too.

Comment: The capturing (or anything else about 'scope') is not related to `async`

Comment: The question I've marked this as a duplicate of refers to anonymous methods, but the principle is exactly the same - hope it helps you.

Comment: @Henk I know it#s not related, but it's very useful in the case of async function and async allows for a delayed execution of the lambda expression when the main method should be done with its code

Comment: Well the duplicate thread does not really help me to understand my code since he actually creates copies of the outer variables in his code while I use them as parameters in a function call. Do I need to decompile my code to get an answer ?

Comment: @JonSkeet -- I stand corrected.  I read the question too quickly.

Comment: There are dozens more duplicates, take your pick. You will find reading a few of them, or a tutorial, is much quicker then understanding the decompiled IL. Look for "captured" and/or "closed over"